# Can backslash be encoded correctly in URL with URL rewrite?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting, urlencode

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC2 project. The problem is when a string which would be rewritten into URL contains a special character such as backslash or question mark, the URL will be wrong, even if I have encoded it before.

For example:

1. I have a product id "**p001\2-2**".
2. I encoded it into "**p001%5C2-2**"
3. The URL `http://domain.com/Product/p001%5C2-2` responds HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

How can I get it correct?

Comment: I have deleted my answer for now, so question could come up in unanswered section, then some asp.net people can take a look. I supposed to understand url encoding stuff but not asp.net-mvc specific one.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use Html.Encode to resolve your backslash.
If the backslash is the only 'special' character in your id, you could use Replace("%5C","\").

Have you checked your routingMap? there has to be a route like

> Product/{prodictID}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `%2F` in my URLs.  Try appending the nOrmalize flag to your rewriteRule.

Example with normalize flag "O" in bold:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L,**O**]
```